# How to combine and save vis.gam plots?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, mgcv

I have created two plots using the vis.gam function. I'm encountering difficulties when attempting to combine and save them. I've attempted various methods such as `grid.arrange`, `ggarrange`, and `plot_layout`, but none seem to work effectively. Although I can arrange them using par(mfrow=c(1, 2)), I prefer using a standard function that allows further formatting. As for saving, the code I tried hasn't been successful. Could someone help with the code to combine and save these plots?
My code for saving plots

```
png("fig.png", width = 465, height = 225, res = 300)
dev. Off()
```

My code to produce plots

```
p1 <- vis.gam(mod1, view = c("x1",  "x2"), theta = 120, plot. Type = "persp")
p2 <- vis.gam(mod1, view = c("x3",  "x4"), theta = 120, plot. Type = "persp")
```

[image]

Comment: Most of the ggplot-based solutions (the ones you list) won't work with base graphics as ggplot and base are two entirely separate plotting ecosystems. However, the underlying grid engine allows you to mix anything and the patchwork package allows base and ggplot graphics to be mixed seamlessly and easily, as illustrated by Allan's answer. The `par()` code you show is the **standard** way to do this with base graphics (see also `layout()`) - as you're not mixing graphics paradigms you don't need patchwork or anything else. Base R has all you need. I have no idea what "further formatting" means

Comment: @GavinSimpson agreed. I initially answered with a base R option, but then saw that this wasn't what the OP wanted. The reasons aren't clear.

Comment: By further formatting, I meant writing letters (a) and (b) on the top right corner. In base R, I could it with `mtext("(b)", xpd=NA, side=3, adj=0, font=2)`.  But they are a bit away from top. I wanted right above top right. Still trying to figure it out with patchwork. This is not part of the question, but since this has been brought up, I wonder if there is an elegant way to add letters to top right of each graph? Thanks

Comment: @Ahsk After Allan's two `wrap_elements()`, you do `p1 + p2` to create the patchwork. If you add `+ plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')` then you'll get panels with an "A" and "B". See `?plot_annotation` in the patchwork package for this and other arguments to add prefixes etc.

Comment: Really appreciate your help with this, Gavin! It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to easily combine the plots with ultimate flexibility, you can use patchwork:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- wrap_elements(panel = ~vis.gam(g, view = c("x1",  "x2"), 
                                     theta = 120, plot.type = "persp"))
p2 <- wrap_elements(panel = ~vis.gam(g, view = c("x3",  "x4"), 
                                     theta = 35, plot.type = "persp"))
ggsave("fig.png", p1 + p2)
```

**fig.png**
[image]

---

**Data used**

The hardest part of answering this question was creating a model from scratch that matched the OP's names, as there was no reproducible example:

```r
library(mgcv)

set.seed(0)
n <- 200
sig2 <- 4
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x4 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
y <- x0^2 + x1 * x2 * x4
mod1 <- gam(y ~ s(x1, x2, x3, x4))
```